# How do I access struct members in ARM assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, struct

I am tasked with recreating a C function in ARM assembly language. This function takes high precision integer objects and adds them together using binary addition.

The function takes 3 parameters, which are pointers to variables of type struct BigInt_T:

```
int BigInt_add(BigInt_T oAddend1, BigInt_T oAddend2, BigInt_T oSum)
```

BigInt_T has two struct members:

```
int iLength; 
/* The number of used digits in the BigInt object */

unsigned int auiDigits[MAX_DIGITS];
/* The digits comprising the BigInt object */
```

I understand that the address of these parameters will be passed into the assembly function as Registers 0 - 2, but I am having trouble trying to access the struct members within each BigInt_T parameter.

In the C version of BigInt_add, accessing these variables is obviously straight-forward:

```
oAddend1->iLength;
oAddend1->auiDigits[i];
```

Can anyone shed some light on how this is done in ARM assembly?

Comment: What are "high precision integer objects"? Integers are always precise.

Comment: And this looks like asking for an ARM assembly tutorial. Unless you have a **specific** problem, please understand such questions are off-topic here. You want to read a book about assembly programming, the ABI you use and the ARM instruction set reference in detail.

Comment: http://www.toves.org/books/arm/

Comment: If you have trouble translating a piece of C code into assembly, [always ask a compiler for help](https://godbolt.org/g/gnlhDN) :) But don't copy-paste the code, rather understand it.

Comment: you are using structs across compile domains?  worse, across languages?  the "variable name" is just the base address, elements in the struct are just offsets, problem is there are no guarantees what the compiler is going to do with that struct, so long as you stay within the compile domain it doesnt matter, vary from that and all bets are off. can get lucky or can be constant maintenance or somewhere in between.

Comment: Try this http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp (see which version you need too)